# Random selection from files with different length

Tags: probability

We have $n$ text files. The texts are randomly generated, so the length of a text can be arbitrarily small, but it can even be arbitrarily large.

We randomly download the part $x$ of the files, and on the other files we randomly retrieve the length of the texts one by one. When we reach the longest text we have seen so far, we process it.

The lengths of the downloaded texts are unknown.

With wich $x$ will we have the highest chance that the longest of the $n$ files will be processed and there will be the shortest text among the downloaded ones?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you pls tell us your thoughts on the problem instead of just typing in the question? It will help us help you better.

Comment: Sounds like the [secretary problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secretary_problem) with the additional wrinkle of requiring the worst candidate to be among those initially rejected.  Is that right?

Comment: At first glance I thought why wouldn't x be the 1/2, considering we choose n / r first, so r should be minimal, when the probability is the highest. Would it be really this simple?